# how to find system locale through code for iphone

Tags: iphone

how to find  system locale  through code for iphone

Answer (score 2):

```
[NSLocale currentLocale];
[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale];
```

Comment: It gives me English(India)  and i need en

Comment: Try using `- (id)objectForKey:(id)key` for `key = NSLocaleLanguageCode`

Answer (score 0):

en is a language code not a locale code did you want?

```
[NSLocale preferredLanguages]
```

It returns an NSArray* of languages in preferred order.
On My iPhone my preferred language has Japanese but my locale language is English. So preferred language is more accurate.